# Are there any RED flags raised when we call UK Home Office for settlement visa status update?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I have applied for my UK UKV1 settlement priority visa 4 weeks ago, I need to know should i call or email them to check status of Visa or not.

I have paid for priority service and its 4th week with no response from home office.

Please Reply

Answer (score 2):

Why would that be an issue? You paid for a service and are genuinely seeking to find its status. While the operator might not have a decision for you, this certainly won't cause any red flags.

People do this all the time, and it has **zero bearing** on the outcome of your application.

> You can contact UK Visas and Immigration from inside or outside the UK.
>
> Contact centre staff cannot give you advice about your personal circumstances.

Source: [UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk)